# mysql_fetch_array and while loop lost first result

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have problem with `mysql_fetch_array()` and `while` loop. I have the query:

```
$tagsquery = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `tags`, `mapa-tagow`, `statusy` WHERE `tags`.`id` = `mapa-tagow`.`tag-id` AND `statusy`.`id` = `mapa-tagow`.`article-id` AND `tags`.`tag` ='$tag' ORDER BY `url` ASC ") or die("ERROR: Tags doesn't exist.");
```

And results in while loop:

```
while($tags = mysql_fetch_array($tagsquery)) {
   echo "<a href='tags.php?url=$url'>$url</a>, ";
}
```

When testing this query in PHPMyAdmin I have one more result than I get in PHP. I dont know why PHP always missing first result.

Comment: IMO you print all results, BUT the first cicle "$url" is empty, then, after the echo, you set $url=$tags['url']; so you miss the first AND the last row. see the @Mathieu code to do right

Comment: Already I improved this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- You're looking at a different copy of the same database
- You've already started fetching your result set earlier than your `while` loop

On a side note, you should build an array of your tag links, and then output them using implode... `while(){ $tag_links[] = '<a href...';} print implode(', ', $tag_links);`

Comment: Thankyou Kenaniah, I had different copy in other line and when I del this line problem disappeared. I did not know that results from db must be used only once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to:

```
while($tags  = mysql_fetch_array($tagsquery)) {
    echo '<a href="tags.php?url='.$tags['url'].'">'.$tags['url'].'</a>, ';
}
```

Note that i took the opportunity to correct your tag output, there are many other ways to output HTML but this is easier to read in most cases.

If you can't spot the problem, i changed your $url to $tags['url'], so i output the URL from the $tags that you got from mysql_fetch_array()

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for fast response, I try this.

Comment: Just to make sure, if i am the one that provided the answer to your problem, why mark another one as the answer?

Comment: I improved both, beacasue I had different copy in my code and my code with echo was bad. Two answers are correct, but I can mark only one answer.